# "Does not name a type"-Error when compile with CMake

Tags: cmake

when I compile my code in Eclipse it works fine. But the process fails if I try to compile it with CMake. It says:

> error: ‘default_random_engine’ does not name a type
>   default_random_engine generator;
>
> error: ‘uniform_int_distribution’ does not name a type
>   uniform_int_distribution distribution;

and some more errors, which I believe are the consequences of these two.

```
class randomInt
{
private:
    int m_max;
    default_random_engine generator;
    uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution;

public:
    randomInt(int max = 0) :
        m_max(max),
        generator(time(0)),
        distribution(0, m_max)
    {}

    int operator ()()
    {
        return distribution(generator);
    }
};



int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    vector<int> vec(100);
    generate(vec.begin(), vec.end(), randomInt(100));

    ostream_iterator<int> streamIt(cout, ",\n");
    copy(vec.begin(), vec.end(), streamIt);

    return 0;
}
```

There is my CMakeLists.txt

```
project(TEST)

# States that CMake required version must be greater than 2.6
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

# Setup sources
set(TEST_SOURCES
        aufgabe2_1.cpp
        aufgabe2_2.cpp
        aufgabe2_3.cpp
        aufgabe2_4.cpp)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "-g -Wall  -std=c++11")

# Build executable
add_executable(main ${TEST_SOURCES})
```

Comment: Probably, Eclipse use different compiler than Cmake. You can check command lines, which compiles executable, in both cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are symbols from the C++ standard library's [pseudo-random number generation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random), but you haven't qualified the symbols with the namespace `std`, so use `std::default_random_engine` and `std::uniform_int_distribution`.